# Error parsing a .csv file to a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, csv

I'm trying to parse a .csv file (and output) to a UITextView in Xcode using Swift 2.0. Having trouble figuring out the right way to call my parseCSV() function to output the parsed .csv to my UITextView

Code:

```
// Parsing Function
func parseCSV (contentsOfURL: NSURL, encoding: NSStringEncoding, error: NSErrorPointer) -> [(id:String, name:String, age: String)]? {
    // Load the CSV file and parse it
    let delimiter = ","
    var peoples:[(id: String, name: String, age: String)]?

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL){
        if let content = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            peoples = []
            let lines:[String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) as [String]

            for line in lines {
                var values:[String] = []
                if line != "" {
                    // For a line with double quotes
                    // we use NSScanner to perform the parsing
                    if line.rangeOfString("\"") != nil {
                        var textToScan:String = line
                        var value:NSString?
                        var textScanner:NSScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                        while textScanner.string != "" {

                            if (textScanner.string as NSString).substringToIndex(1) == "\"" {
                                textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                                textScanner.scanUpToString("\"", intoString: &value)
                                textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                            } else {
                                textScanner.scanUpToString(delimiter, intoString: &value)
                            }

                            // Store the value into the values array
                            values.append(value as! String)

                            // Retrieve the unscanned remainder of the string
                            if textScanner.scanLocation < textScanner.string.characters.count {
                                textToScan = (textScanner.string as NSString).substringFromIndex(textScanner.scanLocation + 1)
                            } else {
                                textToScan = ""
                            }
                            textScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                        }

                        // For a line without double quotes, we can simply separate the string
                        // by using the delimiter (e.g. comma)
                    } else  {
                        values = line.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter)
                    }

                    // Put the values into the tuple and add it to the items array
                    let people = (id: values[0], name: values[1], age: values[2])
                    peoples?.append(people)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return peoples
}
```

Then my viewDidLoad() function is as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var parseText: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/home/CSV?preview=test.csv")
    let error = NSErrorPointer()
    parseText.text = parseCSV(url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: error)
}
```

I get that .text is of type String! (hence causes an error) but I don't know what to call on parseText to ensure the correct type of `[(id:String, name:String, age: String)]`?

Error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/39aXL.jpg

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
     func parseCSV (contentsOfURL: NSURL,encoding: NSStringEncoding, error: NSErrorPointer) 
     [(name:String, detail:String, price: String)]

    // Load the CSV file and parse it

    let delimiter = ","
    var items: [(name:String, detail:String, price: String)]?

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL) {

    if let content = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        items = []
        let lines:[String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) as [String]

        for line in lines {
            var values:[String] = []
            if line != "" {
                // For a line with double quotes
                // we use NSScanner to perform the parsing
                if line.rangeOfString("\"") != nil {
                    var textToScan:String = line
                    var value:NSString?
                    var textScanner:NSScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                    while textScanner.string != "" {
                        if (textScanner.string as NSString).substringToIndex(1) == "\"" {
                            textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                            textScanner.scanUpToString("\"", intoString: &value)
                            textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                        } else {
                            textScanner.scanUpToString(delimiter, intoString: &value)
                        }

                        // Store the value into the values array
                        values.append(value as! String)

                        // Retrieve the unscanned remainder of the string


                        if textScanner.scanLocation < textScanner.string.characters.count {
                            textToScan = (textScanner.string as NSString).substringFromIndex(textScanner.scanLocation + 1)
                        } else {
                            textToScan = ""
                        }
                        textScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                    }

                        // For a line without double quotes, we can simply separate the string
                    // by using the delimiter (e.g. comma)
                } else  {
                    values = line.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter)
                }

                // Put the values into the tuple and add it to the items array
                let item = (name: values[0], detail: values[1], price: values[2])
                items?.append(item)
            }
        }
    }
    }
    return items

}
```